# Sump Pump runs several times a day every day rain or shine

Tags: drainage

I am looking to buy a house that has a French Drain and a sump pump installed.  The basement is dry but the sump pump is constantly pushing what I assume is ground water out.  This occurs several times an hour every day rain or shine.  Is there another solution that will prevent this constant flow of water.

Comment: do you have any information about the system? Maybe pictures would also be helpful. As a side note, my parents had a house surrounded by lots of topsoil, but built on top of a ledge of shale under the topsoil. There was a natural underground spring behind their house. You could set your watch to their sump pump, almost every 40 minutes it'd run for about 90 seconds.

Comment: Depends on the terrain. If there is a slope, to an area lower than the sump pit, you can dig  trench out to daylight and stop pumping, If not, you're stuck with it. Note that a trench typically costs a good deal more than a sump pump; but it sure is cheap to operate, and runs during power outages.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a check valve on the out take pipe after the pump. This prevents water from backing up into the pump and starting the cycle all over again.

Comment: If the discharge isn't into a storm drain, or to somewhere to remove the water, he could be recirculating the same water... or he's simply in an area with odd drainage and a high water table.